# Static Constants : how?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a constants file in a typescript application. The idea is that when `ServiceConstants.AUTH_SERVICE_TOKEN` is called it will return an Opaque token object.

I have tried two implementations:

**ServiceConstants.ts as a namespace**

```
export namespace ServiceConstants {

    export const AUTH_SERVICE_TOKEN: OpaqueToken = new OpaqueToken('AuthService');

}
```

**ServiceConstants.ts as a class**

```
export class ServiceConstants {

    public static AUTH_SERVICE_TOKEN: OpaqueToken = new OpaqueToken('AuthService');

}
```

However, if I call this object I get an

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AUTH_SERVICE_TOKEN' of
>   undefined

How can I initialise the AUTH_SERVICE_TOKEN so that I can simply call `ServiceConstants.AUTH_SERVICE_TOKEN` without having to initialise the variable without having to create a new object? I thought the namespace would have been enough but it seems not.

Cheers

JT

Answer (score 1):

The way typescript deals with this is that one is required to write ServiceConstants.ts as neither a class or namespace. Simply a file with the following single line is enough:

**ServiceConstants.ts**

```
export let AUTH_SERVICE_TOKEN: OpaqueToken = new OpaqueToken('AuthService');
```

Then in the calling file simply

**somefile.ts**

```
import {AUTH_SERVICE_TOKEN} from './ServiceConstants';

console.log(AUTH_SERVICE_TOKEN);
```

HTH

JT